# Construct PDA for ${ \{0^m1^n0^{2n} | n>0\}}$

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have to construct PDA for ${ \{0^m1^n0^{2n} | n>0\}}$

So my idea is to (informally) not pushing anything into the stack while having 0s at first, then when automata start accepting 1s it should push X onto the stack twice on every 1 and then when start accepting 0s it should pop X once every time until stack will be empty.

Is my understanding correct? If not, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. You may need a bit more mechanism to ensure there is at least one 1 after the initial 0's.